# Angularjs : Call directive method as callback from controller

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have a directive that uses a jquery "multiselect" plugin to enhance any < select > with an attribute of "filtermultiselect". My problem is the select is populated via an ajax call and I don't want the directive to run until the < select > has been populated. I amended my directive as follows

```
angular.module('filtermultiselectDirective', [])
    .directive('filtermultiselect', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function( $scope, element, attrs ) {

            $scope.$on('createMultiSelectFilters', function (element) {
                element.multiselect({
                    disableIfEmpty: true,
                    buttonWidth:'100%',
                    enableFiltering: true,
                    includeSelectAllOption: true,
                    enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true                    
                });
            });
        }
    }
});
```

and from my controller I simply use

```
$scope.$broadcast('createMultiSelectFilters');
```

as a callback. However, doesn't work, I get "element.multiselect is not a function".

Any advice for a novice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused by passing "element" as a parameter into the function. The value of element was overwritten by the value of scope. A simple amendment to remove the parameter and everything worked.

```
angular.module('filtermultiselectDirective', [])
    .directive('filtermultiselect', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function( $scope, element, attrs ) {

                $scope.$on('createMultiSelectFilters', function () {

                    element.multiselect({
                        disableIfEmpty: true,
                        buttonWidth:'100%',
                        enableFiltering: true,
                        includeSelectAllOption: true,
                        enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true                    
                    });
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Without being able to verify your code I think you have to wrap your element in jQuery. Try this:

```
angular.module('filtermultiselectDirective', [])
    .directive('filtermultiselect', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function( $scope, element, attrs ) {

            $scope.$on('createMultiSelectFilters', function (element) {
                $(element).multiselect({
                    disableIfEmpty: true,
                    buttonWidth:'100%',
                    enableFiltering: true,
                    includeSelectAllOption: true,
                    enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true                    
                });
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, you pointed me in the right direction. I have posted the actual solution below.

Answer (score 0):

I have an easier way of doing this.
When you do `ng-repeat` in select option simply add this directive.
When ever you reach the last element in `ng-repeat` our `element.multiselect` block will get executed.

```
    angular.module('filtermultiselectDirective', [])
        .directive('filtermultiselect', function() {
             return function ($scope, element, attrs) {

                   if ($scope.$last) {
                      element.multiselect({
                         disableIfEmpty: true,
                         buttonWidth:'100%',
                         enableFiltering: true,
                         includeSelectAllOption: true,
                         enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true                    
                    });

                   }
              }
    });
```

**Update :** it should be  `$(element).multiselect`

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. There are many ways to solve the same problem. The solution that worked for me is now below. Cheers!